# How to keep both Mavericks menu bars opaque in two monitor setup

Tags: display, menu-bar, macos

Mavericks shows the menu bar in both monitors when you have two. That's great, but the menu bar in the passive desktop turns translucent, which is a bit annoying. Is there a way to keep both menu bars opaque at all times? Setting the menu bar opaque in the desktop settings affects only the active monitor.

Answer (score 2):

I just found a fix for this. Check out this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_OMZuFRhUhw&feature=youtu.be) I made.

Step 1. change the order your displays are in.

Step 2. set to opaque.

Step 3. change back the order, now you have opaque on both bars.

Comment: Ahh I misread your poste. My fix is only to set both opaque. It still does that weird thing when focus in one display the bar in dimmed in the other.

Answer (score 2):

you really can't do this but you can:

hide the second display's menu bar by going into SysPref -> Mission Control-> and uncheck Displays have separate Spaces.

I'm sure there will be an update soon enough that allows you to dedicate one display as your Control display, for lack of a better term.

... in researching this tho I did find a neat app called bartender which cleans up your bar.  not free and I'm not linking it cause I have no interest in the company at all, but I am giving the trial mode a shot right now. 
Good Luck